# How to write media queries for each device size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to develop a responsive web page using media queries.
I have also wrote media queries for mobile, tables & desktops.

But i am not able to understand that if I am writing the set of css code for device max-width:320px , then same code i have to write again for another device i.e 640px with difference sizes.

I am confused whether this is the correct way of writing media queries as i am writing the same set of css code for each & every device size again & again.

Please help me to proceed furthur as i am new to media queries.
And also i am confused whether to go for adaptive layout or responsive layout?

---

That's great of you & I appreciate the helpful answers given by you all.
I have given a task by company where they told me that i cannot use any frameworks for designing responsive webpage, I only have to use media queries for this.

Comment: This post may help you 'https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/'

Comment: the idea of media query is that devices with screen sizes satisfying the statements will use the css definitions. it is possible for a device to be using css definitions in multiple media queries

Answer (score 0):

The idea of media queries and of cascading style sheets in general is to progressively enhance your as you go forth.

This means: start your design aiming at mobile. Once done with that add a media query for your next bigger targeted viewport size.

In this query overwrite all styling that needs to be different for this viewport.

And so on ...

Want you do not want to do is writing all styles again an again.

Check out some popular frameworks to get inspiration like twitter bootstrap, html boilerplate or foundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

This might clear all your doubts.This framework makes your work a lot easier. http://getbootstrap.com/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the media queries you're telling to your code  -Bro if the width if bigger than this "size here" (320px, 240em whatever....)   then use this piece of code.

else if "next bigger size here" then use this other piece of code, and the same with the next @media queries

There is two ways to use it.
Coding thinking in mobile first  (ULTRA MEGA recommended)  or not :)

This mean, you create code for the small browser and then start adding mediaqueries for phablet, tablet  and then desktop and wide screen.

This is so useful because help you to add in the page only the really important content and avoid the useless ton of information. because you started designing the small size and have to compress all the usefull info and put inside :)

[Learn more about mobile first technique](https://stratechery.com/2015/mobile-first/)

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
 nav li {
  display: inline-block;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the design is the same, lets say for desktop to large wide monitors, we can do something like

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 800px) and (max-device-width: 2048px) { 
    /* STYLES HERE */
}
```

supposing you want the same design for every desktop screen. This will help you cutting the code down and not rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

the below example you can understand than it is essay to understand the media queries.

```
1) if you say - min-device-width:320PX; this is last breakpoint of your design, below your design doesn't work.
2) if you say - max-width:420px; - this pice of code work until the 420px only after that the code which you mentioned in the breakpoint that doesn't work in remain widths. 

basic break point: 320px -mobile size
                   480px -mobile size, 640px -mobile size, 
                   768px -heigh-end phones,
                   1024px - pad.
                   as remain widths may be seems to work in desktop width.


@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
```

}

hope you get one idea if you read clearly.